# Why is this code cutting out the last line in text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, text

In the file below, I use the video [that you can find here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qbjmb_1hV4) to make a type-writer effect on screen. I'm having a bit of an issue with it at this time.
For whatever reason, it's cutting off the last letter whenever I use it (i.e. putting in "Hello there" types out "Hello ther"). Any ideas on why this is happening?

The programming I am using is a modified version to fit my game:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TypeWriterEffect : MonoBehaviour {

public float delay = 0.1f;
public float startDelay = 0f;
public string fullText;
public bool showGameHS;
public bool showTotalScore;
public string totalGameScore;
private string currentText = "";

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    totalGameScore = PlayerPrefs.GetString("totalGameScore"); // total score throughout the game
    if (showTotalScore)
    {
        fullText = TimerScript.fullScore.ToString() + "."; // a "." is added to fix this issue
    }
    else if (showGameHS) // the local highscore
    {
        fullText = totalGameScore + "."; // a "." is added to fix this issue
    }
    StartCoroutine(ShowText());
}

IEnumerator ShowText(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startDelay); // this was added on as a basic start delay

    for (int i = 0; i < fullText.Length; i++){
        currentText = fullText.Substring(0,i);
        this.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `i < fullText.Length` always stops one index before the complete length of the string -> substring cuts of the last symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop is looping from `0` to `Length - 1`.  Then you are using this variable to tell `Substring` the number of characters to return.  It returns 0 characters the first time.  At the end, it returns all but the last character.

You can either add 1 to the length argument, or change the bounds of your `for` loop:

```
for (int length = 1; length <= fullText.Length; length++){
    currentText = fullText.Substring(0, length);
    this.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
}
```